# How to write a DSL that is not in isolation to the block's environment?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dsl

I am trying to write a small Ruby DSL and have stumbled upon an inconvenience. Right now my "DSL" code is https://gist.github.com/0379b07f516f4f322204 and my implementation code (inside an .html.erb file) is:

```
html_table_for @users do |t, user|
  t.field :username, link_to(user.username, :action => 'show', :id => user.id)
  t.field :email
  t.field :roles, user.roles.map(&:code).join(', ')
end
```

The implementation code does not look much like a DSL because of the `t.field` instead of simply `field`. By replacing `@block.call` in the DSL code (line 34) with `instance_exec(@block)` I almost get what I want but then I lose all the ActionView goodness (namely `link_to`).

**Is there a way to make available in the block the instance methods of my little DSL class while at the same time keeping availability of the helper methods of ActionPack included in Rails?**

Answer (score 3):

I posted a detailed answer to [a similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936146/tutorials-for-writing-dsl-in-ruby/13142331#13142331).

Short answer: check out the [Docile](http://ms-ati.github.com/docile/) gem -- it makes this very easy for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible (albeit hacky and confusing) to get both, by [using method delegation](http://www.dan-manges.com/blog/ruby-dsls-instance-eval-with-delegation):

```
class TableHelper
  def initialize(&block)
    # get a reference to 'self' in the block's scope:
    @self_before_instance_eval = eval "self", block.binding
    instance_eval &block
  end

  # delegate all unknown methods to the calling object:
  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    @self_before_instance_eval.send method, *args, &block
  end

  # Other helper methods:

  def field(name, url)
    # ...
  end

end
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
def some_helper(arg); end

Table.new do
  field :name, some_helper("foo")
end
```

Be careful when using this approach though: you still can't use instance variables from the calling object:

```
@field_url = "http://foo"

Table.new do
  # url will be nil, since the ivar does not exist on the Table
  field :name, @field_url 
end
```